# K&R Exercise 1-9 solution C programming

Tags: c, getchar

The task is to make a C program that replaces multiple blanks with a single blank and I found this solution on another StackOverflow question:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ') {
        while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
            ;
        putchar(' ');
        if (c == EOF) break;
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

It works but I am puzzled by the second while loop:

```
while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
            ;
```

How does line this even remove any white spaces? I thought it just does nothing until it comes across another non-blank character. So then if a sentence had 4 blanks then I would expect it to turn into 5 blanks because your just adding another blank with `putchar(' ')` ? Does it remove the excess blank spaces in a way I'm not aware of?

Comment: The `putchar` call is outside the `while` body (beyond that, you've already answered your question).

Comment: As soon as a ' ' is encountered it's going to read all other characters until a non ' ' is found (the second while loop you mentioned). It then outputs a single ' ' and whatever character it found at the end of the space block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program reads (using `getchar`) a string from standard input and the outputs (using `putchar`) the same string to standard output **but leaving out the excess spaces**.  So effectively it "removes" the extra spaces.

The `while` loop skips over a consecutive block of whitespace in the input while outputting nothing, and then after the loop is done, outputs a single space.  That's how it "removes" the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
            ;
```

This bit skips over spaces. After skipping all of them,

```
putchar(' ');
```

puts one space.

This replaces groups of spaces with one.

Comment: okay this is pretty strange (coming from python) but I think I get it

Comment: C *is* different the Python for sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` reads one character at a time. At each iteration it reads a character and check if it is a space or not. If the character read is a space then read another one until it finds a non-white-space character. After break out of loop `putchar(' ');` is executed and prints a space.